# Grabbing URLs from Sanitized URLs

Tags: bash, parsing, notepad++

A notification service we were using over the last couple of months suddenly started to sanitize their URL inputs.

However, what we were doing as typical operational work is to put this email through a regex filter on notepad++ grab the URLs and send them to a data analyzer like Splunk.

This is my old regex:

```
hxxps?://.+-?.?\.\w+/
```

Which used to work since their previous sanization method was changing the http/s for hxxp/s.

And I would have a list of the URLs

```
new 4 (15 hits)
    Line 3: * Payload delivery/url               : hxxp://gxxx.by/
    Line 14: * Payload delivery/url               : hxxp://dawdas.cm/
    Line 15: * Payload delivery/url               : hxxp://dawfafa.ru/
    Line 16: * Payload delivery/url               : hxxp://dwasa-da.fr/
    Line 17: * Payload delivery/url               : hxxp://hdawwwwffa.com/
```

But now the URLs were changed to this:

```
new 4 (15 hits)
    Line 3: * Payload delivery/url               : hxxp://gxxx[.]by/
    Line 14: * Payload delivery/url               : hxxp://dawdas[.]cm/
    Line 15: * Payload delivery/url               : hxxp://dawfafa[.]ru/
    Line 16: * Payload delivery/url               : hxxp://dwasa-da[.]fr/
    Line 17: * Payload delivery/url               : hxxp://hdawwwwffa[.]com/
```

I am just wondering if there is a way to parse through this with Notepad++ or do I need to use bash which is part of another project, but for now we want to do it as a quick operational task.

Comment: so you just want to replace `[.]` with `.` ? `sed -i 's/\[\.\]/./' file` Or you may have to fix the regex a  little. Good luck.

Comment: Yeah I just realized this, but I also would like to get a formatted result that I can just copy paste and copy to somewhere.

I guess I'll just do this till I can use sed or cut on a way or another.

Cheers,